# Github Actions: How use strategy/matrix with script

Tags: github-actions

I have workflow that needs to have a loop for the steps, which is perfect with strategy/matrix.

The only problem is that strategy/matrix needs to be set by a constant.

Is it possible to use strategy matrix with a output of a script?

```
name: tests
on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ${{ ubuntu-latest }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        versions: $(./script.py)

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
 .......
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can generate matrix in JSON in one job and set it to the second job.

GitHub added this feature in April: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-04-15-github-actions-new-workflow-features/

### Workflow example

```
name: build
on: push
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - id: set-matrix
      run: echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"include\":[{\"project\":\"foo\",\"config\":\"Debug\"},{\"project\":\"bar\",\"config\":\"Release\"}]}"
  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.job1.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: echo ${{ matrix.project }}
    - run: echo ${{ matrix.config }}
```

First job sets output variable `matrix` to JSON that contains two configurations:

```
{
  "include": [
    {
      "project": "foo",
      "config": "Debug"
    },
    {
      "project": "bar",
      "config": "Release"
    }
  ]
}
```

Equivalent in .yml:

```
  job2:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        include:
        - project: foo
          config: Debug
        - project: bar
          config: Release
```

Do not forget to escape quotes `\"` and print JSON in one line.

### More complex Workflow example

It [detects changed files](https://github.community/t/check-pushed-file-changes-with-git-diff-tree-in-github-actions/17220/10) and runs build job for changed directories. If directory name starts with OS name, it uses that name as runs-on.

```
name: Build
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  generate-matrix:
    name: Generate matrix for build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Check changed files
        id: diff
        run: |
          # See https://github.community/t/check-pushed-file-changes-with-git-diff-tree-in-github-actions/17220/10
          if [ $GITHUB_BASE_REF ]; then
            # Pull Request
            git fetch origin $GITHUB_BASE_REF --depth=1
            export DIFF=$( git diff --name-only origin/$GITHUB_BASE_REF $GITHUB_SHA )
            echo "Diff between origin/$GITHUB_BASE_REF and $GITHUB_SHA"
          else
            # Push
            git fetch origin ${{ github.event.before }} --depth=1
            export DIFF=$( git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} $GITHUB_SHA )
            echo "Diff between ${{ github.event.before }} and $GITHUB_SHA"
          fi
          echo "$DIFF"
          # Escape newlines (replace \n with %0A)
          echo "diff=$( echo "$DIFF" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/%0A/g' )" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Set matrix for build
        id: set-matrix
        run: |
          # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953566/11948346
          DIFF="${{ steps.diff.outputs.diff }}"
          JSON="{\"include\":["

          # Loop by lines
          while read path; do
            # Set $directory to substring before /
            directory="$( echo $path | cut -d'/' -f1 -s )"

            if [ -z "$directory" ]; then
              continue # Exclude root directory
            elif [ "$directory" == docs ]; then
              continue # Exclude docs directory
            elif [ "$path" == *.rst ]; then
              continue # Exclude *.rst files
            fi

            # Set $os. "ubuntu-latest" by default. if directory starts with windows, then "windows-latest"
            os="ubuntu-latest"
            if [ "$directory" == windows* ]; then
              os="windows-latest"
            fi

            # Add build to the matrix only if it is not already included
            JSONline="{\"directory\": \"$directory\", \"os\": \"$os\"},"
            if [[ "$JSON" != *"$JSONline"* ]]; then
              JSON="$JSON$JSONline"
            fi
          done <<< "$DIFF"

          # Remove last "," and add closing brackets
          if [[ $JSON == *, ]]; then
            JSON="${JSON%?}"
          fi
          JSON="$JSON]}"
          echo $JSON

          # Set output
          echo "matrix=$( echo "$JSON" )" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  build:
    name: Build "${{ matrix.directory }}" on ${{ matrix.os }}
    needs: generate-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd ${{ matrix.directory }}
          echo "${{ matrix.directory }} ${{ matrix.os }}"
```

Comment: Can you provide Powershell alternative for Windows Runner for the multline json and matrix conversion?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new example, it was a really helpful answer. Thank you @ArtemSBulgakov !

This one uses Github `strategy.matrix` of Github Actions with `fromJson` to collect only the directories in a Pull Request with changes and make a Syntax Review and Format Review of Terraform using https://github.com/dflook/terraform-github-actions

```yaml
---
name: Check Syntax
on: [pull_request]

jobs:
  generate-matrix:
    name: Generate matrix for build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Check changed files
        id: diff
        run: |
          # See https://github.community/t/check-pushed-file-changes-with-git-diff-tree-in-github-actions/17220/10
          export DIFF=$( git diff --dirstat=files,0,cumulative ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' )
          echo "$DIFF"
          # Escape newlines (replace \n with %0A)
          echo "::set-output name=diff::$( echo "$DIFF" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/%0A/g' )"
      - name: Set matrix for build
        id: set-matrix
        run: |
          # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953566/11948346
          DIFF="${{ steps.diff.outputs.diff }}"
          JSON="{\"tfpaths\":["

          # Loop by lines
          while read path; do
          # Add item to the matrix only if it is not already included
          JSONline="\"$path\","
          if [[ "$JSON" != *"$JSONline"* ]]; then
          JSON="$JSON$JSONline"
          fi
          done <<< "$DIFF"

          # Remove last "," and add closing brackets
          if [[ $JSON == *, ]]; then
          JSON="${JSON%?}"
          fi
          JSON="$JSON]}"
          echo $JSON
          # Set output
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::$( echo "$JSON" )"

  validate:
    name: Check Terraform syntax on "${{ matrix.tfpaths }}"
    needs: generate-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: terraform validate
        uses: dflook/terraform-validate@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ matrix.tfpaths }}

  check-format:
    name: Check Terraform format on "${{ matrix.tfpaths }}"
    needs: generate-matrix
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: terraform fmt
        uses: dflook/terraform-fmt-check@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ matrix.tfpaths }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [@ArtemSBulgakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11948346/artemsbulgakov)'s solution as a starting point but got stuck trying to generate the `matrix` from some other output, rather than explicit json string.

If you are like me and want a way to feed the `matrix` from other `outputs` see below.

---

In this example, I want to fetch the latest pull requests from GitHub using the [`octokit/request-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-api-request) action, then performing some checks on each pull request. Sounds pretty simple but transforming the output (i.e. `steps.fetch.outputs.data`) into something like this...

```json
{
  "includes": [{ "number": 1, "title": "my first pr " }]
}
```

...proved to be much harder than I expected. You may be more skilled at doing this with one of the [available `shell`'s](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell) GitHub provides but then you still have to somehow pass the `output` values to the `run` script and then back out again. If someone knows an easy way to do this, I would be happy to see it.

So I decided to create the [`nickofthyme/object-remap`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/object-remapping-from-json-to-json) GitHub action to make this a little easier. I won't get into all the usages (see the `README.md`) but an example usage to set the `matrix.includes` using [Object filters](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#object-filters) (i.e. `.*.`) would look like this...

```yaml
name: 'PR Check'

on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 0 * * *' # once a day

jobs:
  fetch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.save.outputs.json }}
    steps:
      - name: Fetch GH pulls
        id: fetch
        uses: octokit/request-action@v2.x
        with:
          route: GET /repos/{repo}/pulls?state=open
          repo: ${{ github.repository }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
      - name: Store matrix
        id: save
        uses: nickofthyme/object-remap@v1
        with:
          include.*.number: ${{ toJSON(fromJSON(steps.fetch.outputs.data).*.number) }}
          include.*.title: ${{ toJSON(fromJSON(steps.fetch.outputs.data).*.title) }}
          include.*.username: ${{ toJSON(fromJSON(steps.fetch.outputs.data).*.user.login) }}

  pr-checks:
    name: "PR #${{ matrix.number }} - ${{ matrix.title }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: fetch
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJSON(needs.fetch.outputs.matrix) }}
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
      - name: Echo pr number
        run: echo "pr number: ${{ matrix.number }}"
      - name: Echo title
        run: echo "title: ${{ matrix.title }}"
      - name: Echo username
        run: echo "username: ${{ matrix.username }}"
```

For example, if this workflow were run on [`react`](https://reactjs.org/)'s first 2 PRs

```sh
curl https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls?per_page=2&direction=asc&state=all
```

The `steps.fetch.outputs.data`, omitting `head`, `base` and `_links` for brevity, would be...

```json
[
  {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/1",
      "id": 6001916,
      "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NjAwMTkxNg==",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1",
      "diff_url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1.diff",
      "patch_url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/1.patch",
      "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues/1",
      "number": 1,
      "state": "closed",
      "locked": false,
      "title": "Run each test in its own <iframe>",
      "user": {
          "login": "benjamn",
          "id": 5750,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjU3NTA=",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/5750?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/benjamn",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/benjamn/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
      },
      "body": "This is not blocking the initial launch, so feel free to put it on the back-burner for now.\n\nThe Jasmine test harness still runs in the parent window and reports to PhantomJS via `window.callPhantom`, but each test `<iframe>` has its own copy of `react-test.js` and each individual test module is required in the global context of a separate `<iframe>`.\n\nThis gives us a significant approximation of the benefits of mocking, at least in terms of isolating tests from one another.\n\ncr @jeffmo @zpao\n",
      "created_at": "2013-05-29T20:20:53Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-07-16T22:39:07Z",
      "closed_at": "2013-06-03T17:58:02Z",
      "merged_at": "2013-06-03T17:58:02Z",
      "merge_commit_sha": "7a72883d48e00854a41a1cdff99a2544c1721dcc",
      "assignee": null,
      "assignees": [],
      "requested_reviewers": [],
      "requested_teams": [],
      "labels": [],
      "milestone": null,
      "draft": false,
      "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/1/commits",
      "review_comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/1/comments",
      "review_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/comments{/number}",
      "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues/1/comments",
      "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/statuses/603c9ef6a8d70d3cf29ee9d0a9d7969abce48ac4",
      "head": {},
      "base": {},
      "_links": {},
      "author_association": "CONTRIBUTOR",
      "auto_merge": null,
      "active_lock_reason": null
  },
  {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/2",
      "id": 6002192,
      "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NjAwMjE5Mg==",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2",
      "diff_url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2.diff",
      "patch_url": "https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2.patch",
      "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues/2",
      "number": 2,
      "state": "closed",
      "locked": false,
      "title": "[docs] Fix button links on bottom of home",
      "user": {
          "login": "paulshen",
          "id": 2266187,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNjYxODc=",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2266187?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/paulshen",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/paulshen/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
      },
      "body": "The buttons on the index were pointing at wrong paths.\n",
      "created_at": "2013-05-29T20:31:39Z",
      "updated_at": "2014-06-27T04:39:06Z",
      "closed_at": "2013-05-29T20:32:25Z",
      "merged_at": "2013-05-29T20:32:25Z",
      "merge_commit_sha": "9aa4d2bc27c38b01c9c8f3436bd729d5e656cb1b",
      "assignee": null,
      "assignees": [],
      "requested_reviewers": [],
      "requested_teams": [],
      "labels": [],
      "milestone": null,
      "draft": false,
      "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/2/commits",
      "review_comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/2/comments",
      "review_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls/comments{/number}",
      "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues/2/comments",
      "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/statuses/c5b4fe9e88a9a3b43cfd9b7e5383096bd9e213ef",
      "head": {},
      "base": {},
      "_links": {},
      "author_association": "CONTRIBUTOR",
      "auto_merge": null,
      "active_lock_reason": null
  }
]
```

And the value of `steps.save.outputs.json` (aka `needs.fetch.outputs.matrix`) would be...

```json
{ 
  "includes": [
    {
        "state": "closed",
        "title": "Run each test in its own <iframe>",
        "username": "benjamn"
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "title": "[docs] Fix button links on bottom of home",
        "username": "paulshen"
    }
  ]
}
```

...which can easily be passed to [`jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) which would trigger two `pr-checks` jobs.

> One final note: I attempted to just pass the matrix array of values to `jobs.<job_id>.strategy.matrix.includes` but this fails because `matrix.includes` does **not** accept GitHub [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions) as a value. So nesting values in `includes` is the way to go!

Comment: Can you provide Powershell alternative for Windows Runner for the multline json and matrix conversion?

Comment: I am not familiar with Powershell but are you referring to the `object-remap` action not working on Windows machines? If so please open an issue on GH, if not please elaborate.

Comment: runs-on: [self-hosted,X64,dev,Windows]
   outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.parsejson.outputs.matrix }}
   steps:
     - name: Parse JSON and read the input variable definitions 
       id: parsejson
       run: |
        $content= (Get-Content "${{github.workspace}}\${{env.input_json}}" -Raw)
         echo "::set-output name=matrix::$( echo "$content" )"

Comment: - run: |
           echo "${{fromJson(steps.parsejson.outputs.matrix).postcheckout}}"  -> this is throwing error   Error: .github/workflows/start.yml (Line: 50, Col: 13):
  Warning: Encountered an error when evaluating display name ${{ format('echo "{0}"
 ', fromJson(steps.parsejson.outputs.matrix).postcheckout) }}. The template is not valid. .github/workflows/start.yml (Line: 50, Col: 13): Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 1, position 1.
Error: .github/workflows/start.yml (Line: 50, Col: 13):
Error: The template is not valid. .github/workflows/start.yml (Line: 50, Col

Comment: Is this in a public repo? Do you have a link? Otherwise open a new SO issue and link it here for me to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

here it is another smart silution for matrix parametrize

https://github.com/nickofthyme/object-remap

```
...
env:
  PYTHON_VERSION: '[3.10, 3.11, 3.12]'
  OS_TYPE: '["ubuntu-latest", "windows-latest", "macos-latest"]'
...
jobs:
  matrix_config:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.prepare.outputs.json }}

    steps:
      - name: Prepare matrix JSON Object
        id: prepare
        uses: nickofthyme/object-remap@v2.0.0
        with:
          __case: kebab
          os: ${{ env.OS_TYPE }}
          python_version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
...
  someJob:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    needs: [ matrix_config ]

    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJSON(needs.matrix_config.outputs.matrix) }}

    steps:
...
      - name: Set-Up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The method used in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62953566/391691) is [deprecated](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/) The first example can be rewritten as:

```
name: build
on: push
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
    - id: set-matrix
      run: echo "matrix={\"include\":[{\"project\":\"foo\",\"config\":\"Debug\"},{\"project\":\"bar\",\"config\":\"Release\"}]}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.job1.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
    - run: echo ${{ matrix.project }}
    - run: echo ${{ matrix.config }}
```