# Set GitHub Action Output Variable Inside Index List Expression

Tags: github-actions

I execute a **main-action** with an **entrypoint.sh** bash script that returns an environment variable named **MATRIX_LIST** that looks like this **[value1,value2,value3]** and then I transfer it to the next job (**second_job**) as output.

The problem is I want the **strategy.matrix** within the **second_job** to run as the number of **${{ needs.first_job.outputs.MATRIX_LIST }}** but it does not work and return me this error

> Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'second_job'.
> (Line: 44, Col: 19): Unexpected value '[value1,value2,value3]'

```
jobs:
  first_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Return the MATRIX_LIST environment variable
    outputs:
      MATRIX_LIST: ${{ env.MATRIX_LIST }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Local Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Main Action Step (Set MATRIX_LIST into GITHUB_ENV)
        uses: ./.github/actions/main-action
        with:
          first-key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}

  second_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Trigger the matrix job N times depending to the MATRIX_LIST output variable
    needs: [first_job]

    strategy:
      matrix:
        services: ${{ needs.first_job.outputs.MATRIX_LIST }}

    steps:
      - name: Print the value of service name ${{ matrix.service }}
        run: |
              echo "Hello: ${{ matrix.service }}"
```

Is it possible to set an outputs variable within GitHub's index/list expression syntax?

***Updated (entrypoint.sh Bash Script):***

```
function Convert_Array_To_Matrix_Index_List()
{
    services_array=(value1,value2,value3)

    for SERVICE in ${services_array[@]}; do
        second_array+=("${SERVICE}")
    done

    MATRIX_LIST=`(IFS=,; echo "[${second_array[*]}]")`
    echo "MATRIX_LIST=${MATRIX_LIST}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977364/github-actions-how-use-strategy-matrix-with-script?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not using or can generate a JSON format

Comment: Why can't you just transform it?

Comment: I've modified my question and add the entrypoint.sh bash script. :) It will be great if you could share with me the corrections I need to make to my code :)))